# Displaying images at run time inside a panel in c# using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I want to display images based on a search query inside a panel at run time in c#. Its a web application. The code i wrote for displaying images at run time is not working. Here's the code.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageMap image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageMap();
image.ImageUrl = reader["image"].ToString(); // Take the path from the database
Panel1.Controls.Add(image); // Display the image
```

The code is working fine, but the image is not getting displayed inside the panel.

Comment: The path of the image is absolute (e.g. /images/small/001.jpg) or relative (../small/001.jpg)? In any case view the HTML code to see how exactly the HTML of your ImageMap is rendered

Comment: @codingstill The path is still absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try something else you *could* do this:

```
var image = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
image.Attributes["src"] = reader["image"].ToString();
Panel1.Controls.Add(image);
```

(Your panel is visible, right?)

Comment: What tag is being rendered by the image? If it has a `src` attribute, does it point to an actual image? Please post your `Panel`code and anything inside it as well.